# Vim's relativenumber setting and multiple buffers

Tags: vim

*I like the relative number setting. I'm refactoring code at the moment (translation: explodicating 5 year old terrible methods and replacing them with nice code) and I find it useful to have the setting active on files as I open them*

I frequently either open multiple buffers or use a [client/server vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_in_already_running_vim_from_elsewhere) to contain all my open buffers/files and have noticed that the relative number only seems to apply to the first buffer (and not the remaining buffers when I have `set rnu` in my .vimrc file.)

Is it expected behaviour for rnu to only initially apply to the first buffer until you manually set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is expected behavior, unless you explicitly set it globally with ":setglobal":

```
:setglobal relativenumber
```

See "`:help :setglobal`" and "`:help 'relativenumber'`" (with the single quotes as part of the command).

Comment: Ah that makes total sense thank you. I never considered setglobal

Comment: Did you try it? It's not what the docs say and it's not how it behaves here.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if you want the same behavior as me... to have all buffers use `relativenumber` by default. If that is the case then you would think `set relativenumber` in `.vimrc` would work but it doesn't. Instead I used `autocmd BufEnter * set relativenumber`.

Comment: +1. Worked for me with VIM on windows. The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: This plus `autocmd BufLeave * set number` (set back to normal numbering when leaving buffer) worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you have both numbering, and relative numbering turned on in your vimrc:

```
set nu
" maybe lots more configuration here or in other sourced config files
set rnu
```

For some reason, this works in the first buffer/tab, but not in subsequent buffers/tabs, so the solution is to just have one or the other set but not both:

```
" turn on line numbering (either relative (rnu) or traditional (nu))
set rnu
```

Other answers get around the problem with your vimrc file but don't fix it, but they work also.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem. Thanks, man!